# Rhythmbox Music Player is getting opened when arrow Keys(up, down, right, left) are tapped

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, rhythmbox

Without changing any settings, Rhythmbox Music Player is getting opened when arrow Keys (up, down, right, left) are pressed. For now, only restarting the machine can prevent this weird behavior.

Can somebody let me know the permanent fix for this other than restarting the machine?

Comment: Open settings (top right of screen) and select devices then keyboard then check to see if the arrow keys are set there.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen no arrow key was set there. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: @Kishore when you press arrow keys when terminal is active or gedit is active..or firefox.. is it the same behavior?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes, Same behavior

Comment: @Kishore is this behavior started rite from the installation of OS or later? by the way have you tried to purge and reinstall RhythmBox??

Comment: In the dropdown menu, do you see that by pressing Ctrl and the arrow keys that gives control over over the useage of Rythmbox? Is your Ctrl key latching?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the Control dropdown menu in Rythmbox

Comment: @Graham No, just by pressing arrow keys Rythmbox is opened and only restarting the machine can prevent it.

Comment: @PRATAP  is this behavior started rite from the installation of OS

Answer (score 0):

To me, this appears to be that Sticky Keys has been turned on whether by accident or design.

To check, open System Settings > Universal Settings (on the bottom row) > Typing tab and if Sticky Keys is turned on, turn it off.

[image]

You can also see what is happening when you press the arrow keys by opening a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> and tping xev. This will open a dialogue which will show you what is happening when you press keys from which you may be able to establish the problem and a solution.

Comment: Since it is a random issue , I can only check when it happens next time. But your answer make sense to me and Thank you so much for that.

Comment: @Kishore as it is random, maybe a good idea to run xev as described to see what happens without the issue and then when it occurs again, run xev to make a comparison. Some time ago, someone mentioned that pressing the shift key a number of times can trigger the "sticky keys" on. I've tried this myself as an experiment but I couldn't trigger it. Certainly my Rythmbox in 16.04 LTS works as expected by default.

Comment: Sure Graham, I will do the comparison and try to figure out the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. It was caused by accidentally plugging an old keyboard with 6 pin PS2 connector into the mouse slot!! when I put it in the correct place, the problem went away.